# Street View panorama is grey?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I have built a page that displays different views of a location e.g. roadmap, satellite and streetview.

When I try to display a streetview panorama it is not working. I have a separate div for each map view. Here is an example of the code and html that I am using for the streetview.

```
var panoramaOptions = {
             position: new google.maps.LatLng(-41.34473283543335, 174.7694693629674),
             pov: {
               heading: 34,
               pitch: 10
             },
             visible:true
};
var panorama = new  google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('street_view'),panoramaOptions);
panorama.setVisible(true);

<div class='map-big' id='street_view' style='overflow:hidden;'></div>
```

How can I get this to display the streetview properly?

Comment: I can see the panorama, please post more details.

Comment: I see a panorama as well.  Where are you trying to see? [Here](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_Streetview_lookAtB.html?snaptoroad=-41.34473283543335,%20174.7694693629674) or [here](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_Streetview_lookAtB.html?snaptoroad=-41.344516,174.769449)

Answer (score 0):

Best guess:
I ran into a similar issue with streetview when I tried toggling between standard map view and street view.
I did 2 things to fix the issue:
1. When I switched to street view, I re-ran setPosition on streetview.
    So I ran:
    `g_map.getStreetView().setPosition(g_position);`

1. I used to cache the streetview object
   `g_streetView = g_map.getStreetView();
   g_streetView.setPosition(place);`

   I stopped doing that, and now I always call the long version
   `g_map.getStreetView().setPosition(place);`

Hope this helps!